# Why does tsort not report any loop in this example?

Tags: tsort

How does tsort find the order in the following examples?

Why does tsort not report any loop in this example,

```
$ tsort <<EOF
a b c d c b a b
EOF

a
c
b
d
```

whereas it does in this one? Thanks.

```
$ tsort <<EOF
a b c d d c b a
EOF

tsort: -: input contains a loop:
tsort: a
tsort: b
a
b
tsort: -: input contains a loop:
tsort: c
tsort: d
c
d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no loop in your first input. Let's break it down:

```
a b c d c b a b
```

Or, putting it in pairs:

- a < b
- c < d
- c < b
- a < b (this one specified twice!)

So you have that both "a" and "c" come before "b" and that "c" also comes before "d". But there are no loops there!

On your second example though, what you have is two direct loops, both a < b, b < a (loop!) and also c < d, d < c (loop!)

Putting these in a graph for visualization (you might want to look into the `dot` program) might help you visualize these loops easily!